# How to calculate wire gauge when connecting battery cells in series?

Tags: awg

How does one determine what wire gauge to use when building a battery by connecting lower voltage cells in series?

e.g. Let's say one is building a couple of 12V batteries that are expected to supply 100 amps continuously. The first battery is composed of eight 1.5V cells. The second is composed of two 6V cells.

Using a wire gauge table I've determined that one will need a 4 AWG cable  6' or less in length to handle 100 amps with <3% voltage drop.

What gauge wire should be used to connect the cells from the examples above in series? Should the internal cables also be 4 AWG? Do the number of cells and their respective voltage matter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Current is all that matters - until the voltage gets high enough that insulation breakdown becomes a concern.

Use the same gauge wire in the battery link as you're using in the main circuit.

> The first battery is composed of eight 1.5v cells. The second is composed of two 6v cells.

This sounds like a bad idea. I have never heard of 6 V (capital 'V' for volt) cells but it suggests that you are mixing battery chemistries and these will have different discharge rates and capacities.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know it was case-sensitive. In this case the cell voltage is arbitrary and theoretical. I wanted two distinct contrasting examples.

Comment: This leads me to the conclusion that fewer cells are better simply because it'll take less material to connect them.